# Desktop Shortcut with start in and target properties

Tags: lubuntu, wine, icons, .desktop, desktop-icons

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and i have installed a windows application using wineHQ. In windows the desktop icon has two parameters "Start in" and "Target". The "Start in" path points to a network server path and "Target" points to a file on the C drive followed by a network path file. I would like to know how the Ubuntu .desktop file configured to use the the target and start in parameters. See the configurations under;

**Windows Desktop Shortcut**

Target: C:\ApplicationDirectory\BIN\MyApp.EXE \\ServerName\ApplicationDirectory\FileName

Start in: \\ServerName\ApplicationDirectory

[image: Windows Desktop Shortcut]

**Ubuntu .Desktop file Configuration**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=sudo ~/.wine/MyApplication/BIN/MyApp.EXE smb://ServerName/ApplicationDirectory/FileName
Name=MyApplication
Comment=MyApplication
```

**Questions:**

1. Wine is installed in the root directory and to access the MyApplication directory i have to enter my root password sometimes from **winecfg** the directory is not visible. Is there a way to configure this file to always run as root?
2. How do i configure the "Start in" properties in the .Desktop file to start in my network path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, in the Ubuntu .desktop configuration file, the target is Exec. Start in does not have an equivalent value in Ubuntu .desktop file.  In Windows, the "Start in" field is only valid if the target is a console application or it is command prompt/Powershell. So in Ubuntu, the equivalent of Start In is usually the location of .desktop file.
I hope this is helpful to you and will upvote this post.

Comment: My start in file is on a network directory how can i run the program from the network server and have a desktop shortcut on ubuntu?

Comment: Copy-paste that file and edit the desktop shortcut